Is $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1\frac{n^kx}{(1+n^2x^2)^2}dx=0, \text{ where }k\in\{0,1,2\}$?
Is $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int\limits_0^1\frac{n^kx}{(1+n^2x^2)^2}dx=0, \text{ where }k\in\{0,1,2\}$?
My approach:
We perform a substitution and get
\begin{align*}
\int\limits_0^1\frac{n^kx}{(1+n^2x^2)^2}dx=\int\limits_1^{1+n^2}\frac{n^{k-2}}{2y^2}dy=\frac{n^{k-2}}{2}\frac{(-1)}{y}\Big|_1^{1+n^2}=n^{k-2}\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2(1+n^2)}\right)
\end{align*}
for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. So if $k=0$ or $k=1$ then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int\limits_0^1\frac{n^kx}{(1+n^2x^2)^2}dx=0$, if $k=2$ then the limit attains $\frac{1}{2}$.
I am pretty confident that my soution is correct but the book says that the limit is not $0$ for all three values of $k$. Maybe someone spots a mistake in my proof or maybe it's just a typo in the book?

Everything seems to check out.

Your result is correct. Maybe your book meant that at least one of the values of $k$ yields a non-zero result?

OP is definitely correct. For completeness, for any  $k\in \mathbb R$, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\because & \int_0^1 \frac{n^k x}{\left(1+n^2 x^2\right)^2} d x=\frac{n^k}{2\left(1+n^2\right)}= \frac{n^{k-2}}{2\left(\frac{1}{n^2}+1\right)} \\
\therefore & \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^1 \frac{n^k x}{\left(1+n^2 x^2\right)^2} d x= \frac{n^{k-2}}{2\left(\frac{1}{n^2}+1\right)} 
=\begin{cases}0 & \text { if } k<2 \\
\frac{1}{2} & \text { if } k=2 \\
\infty & \text { if } k>2\end{cases}
\end{aligned}
$$
